# Java Stream with ::new to Kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin

I'm trying to convert the following Spring Security code from Java to Kotlin.

**Java:**

```
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities =
        Arrays.stream(claims.get(AUTHORITIES_KEY).toString().split(","))
            .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Kotlin:**

```
val authorities = Arrays.stream(claims[AUTHORITIES_KEY].toString().split(",".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray())
        .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority())
        .collect(Collectors.toList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>())
```

I get a *Type mismatch* error (`Required:
Function<in String!, out (???..???)>!`) on `.map(SimpleGrantedAuthority())`.  How do I convert the above Java code to Kotlin with a `::new` keyword correctly?

Comment: use `::SimpleGrantedAuthority` instead it is equivalent to `SimpleGrantedAuthority::new` in java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `Arrays.stream` doesn't make the code super readable:

```
val authorities = Arrays.stream(claims.get(AUTHORITIES_KEY).toString().split(",").toTypedArray())
     .map(::SimpleGrantedAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>())
```

However in Kotlin you can do better:

```
val authorities = claims.get(AUTHORITIES_KEY).toString()
                .split(",").filterNot { it.isEmpty() }
                .map(::SimpleGrantedAuthority)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a lambda expression to `map`'s body. What you did there was creating a new instance of `SimpleGrantedAuthority` instead of creating a function that returns a new instance of `SimpleGrantedAuthority`.

It's a subtle difference.

In order to fix your problems, you can use a reference to the constructor:

```
.map(::SimpleGrantedAuthority)
```

or define a lambda expression by hand:

```
.map({ SimpleGrantedAuthority() })
```

---

Also, instead of:

```
claims.get(AUTHORITIES_KEY)
```

you can do:

```
claims[AUTHORITIES_KEY]
```

---

You do not really need to use Stream API in Kotlin. Native Collections API is powerful enough:

```
 val auths = claims[AUTHORITIES_KEY].toString()
   .split(",")
   .filterNot(String::isEmpty)
   .map(::SimpleGrantedAuthority)
```